# How hard would it be to travel to a counter-earth?

Tags: space-travel, counter-earth

The concept of a counter earth was based on highly outdated ideas on how the solar system functioned. It mainly appears in science fiction and ufo theories today. I just watched a video talking about the absurdity of the idea. Either way, I was wondering, how hard would it be for humans or perhaps beings living on this world to travel to the opposite? Thinking about it myself, I would imagine it would be rather hard. We have yet to get to even Mars, which would be a shorter journey (the main reason we haven't gone there is because Nasa took decades to come up with a way to keep astronauts alive long enough to just make the journey). We haven't traveled Venus either, which would actually be easier, but of course that's because you couldn't put a human on its surface due to its current conditions. either way, the distance that would need to be covered would surely be quite vast. How far out would you actually need to go to make the journey? If humans or whatever could make the journey, would that means they could also travel to Jupiter? What are the distances involved? Surely they'd have to get to Mars and the Venus first, but what about the outer planets? I'm assuming it couldn't be done with current technology, but maybe it could? I've never heard of Nasa putting anyone in direct orbit around the sun or even discuss the idea.

Comment: Too many questions in a single post. And please break the wall of text down in something easier on the eyes.

Comment: What all does "travel to" cover? Just orbit once and then slingshot back? Reach it but then suicide crash into the atmosphere/surface? Land successfully but have no way of return? Land but be able to lift back off? Land and have enough resources to start a colony?

Comment: I'm probably talking out of my ass but I expect it would be significantly more difficult than getting to Mars or Venus. Orbital mechanics really don't work in your favour here

Comment: I'm interested in the core question, but suggest that this needs fairly savage editing in order to increase readability and avoid closure.  I would suggest choppping out all but the first 4-5 sentences, then adding something like "What would the thrust and time requirements be for a transit from geostationary orbit around Earth to the point in empty space directly opposite the Earth in its orbit around the sun, compared to Earth-Mars or Earth-Venus transits?"  Keep in mind that probes have been sent all over the place, including the very difficult close-to-Sun missions.

Comment: I know nothing about rocket science, so I wanted it explained in pratical terms. If we could do x, could we do y? If we wanted to y, then what would x have to be? Why assume I'm a rocket scientist that would understand science garbage terminology?

Comment: Before telescope people do not think there are anything out there except Earth, Moon, Sun and stars. To explain lunar eclipse they have to invent a planet which was the counter earth... stupid as it seemed but it was 10x better than a giant dog munching on the moon and babies were sacrificed to appease the hungry deity.